# How do I fix the ImportError?

Tags: python, urllib3

So here is the import section:

```
from  urllib3.packages import six
from .packages.six import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection 
from .packages.six import HTTPException
```

The Import Error raised at Line 2 is: `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPConnection' from 'urllib3.packages.six'`
And also there is a prompt which says: `"HTTPException" is not accessedPylance`

[image: Everything related to above code section is marked with arrow]

Comment: Is your file or directory called ‘urllib3’?

Comment: The prompt which says: ```"HTTPException" is not accessedPylance``` just means that you haven't used ```HTTPException``` in your code

Comment: @LeopardShark yes it is and also look at the picture in the post, in it current file and directory is `connection.py` & `urllib3` respectively.

Comment: *Why* is your project called `urllib3`? You tagged the `urllib3` library in your question, which means you're aware of the very popular Python library already called that. Naming a new project the same thing is only going to create confusion.

Comment: @Nin17 Ok understood about it, Do you have any idea why do i get `ImportError` at `from .packages.six import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection `

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I had to import urllib3 while working with a GitHub repo. However I have to go through all these compatibility issues.

Comment: @Ritu1969 There isn't a function called HTTPConnection in urllib3.packages.six. You can't import it because it doesn't exist! Is there a source for why you think this function should be in this file?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo op isn't making a new package called ```urllib3``` they're trying to use it

Comment: @Nin17 Sorry but I don't have the source which you are asking for. I was just trying to run a Github repo, and imported urrlib3 and other packages which was necessary. However the code somehow failed on this issue. What I don't understand is if "there isn't a function called HTTPConnection in urllib3.packages.six." then why there is a Import line in file `connection.py` of the same `urllib3`. and Do you see the problem occurs in a module(i.e. connection.py) of a imported package, urllib3. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing urllib3.

Comment: @Ritu1969 That is not the line in my ```connection.py```, the line in mine is ```from .packages import six```    
```from .packages.six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection```  
```from .packages.six.moves.http_client import HTTPException ``` which works for me

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm using urllib3 version 1.26.9

Answer (score 0):

With urllib3 version 1.26.9 the correct imports are:

```
from urllib3.packages import six
from urllib3.packages.six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection
from urllib3.packages.six.moves.http_client import HTTPException
```